# How do I implement a "choose one from list" form in Joomla?

Tags: forms, joomla, joomla2.5

I'm using Joomla 2.5 as CMS for our project website. I would like to ask users to pick ONE unique choice out of a predefined set of items (to be more specific: choose one country from a list of countries) such that the chosen item will be unavailable/ grayed out for other users in the future.
I assume that I would need some kind of database in the background that tracks the available  items and stores which items have already been picked.
Apart from standard Joomla 2.5, I have access to RSforms pro, but it doesn't seem to do the job. Any suggestions?

Comment: Is this field intended for user profiles or for a contact form?

Comment: For a kind of contact form. To clarify: I don't want people having to register as website users, just to navigate to a page, make their choice and be done.

Comment: You should add one more filed to the DB for managing the items that are picked.This option not available with RSforms or any other component,So you should cutomise the things.

Answer (score 2):

Give the [Joomla MVC Component Creator](http://www.notwebdesign.com/joomla-component-creator/) a go. Sounds like you could make it with a standard Joomla list field.